# Realm Object Server SyncUser reset / change password

Tags: realm

Is there a way to reset a `SyncUser`'s password on the backend (user forgot password), or let a user change there current password?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you unfortunately cannot change the password for a user. In our next release of Realm Object Server, we will include a tool for doing exactly this.

What you can do current is to remove the user account and recreate it with a new password in the "Users" section of the dashboard. This will, however, not give the new user access to the Realm files the old user had access to.

Comment: Hi, any update on this? I found that on realm-object-server you now have full support for password reset, but I can't find any way to just change the password